# How do I get the designation of a model field?

Tags: django, sqlite

How can I put a designation (such as label in forms) in the model so that later it can be obtained, as here, for example:

models:

```
class characterist_0001_pkModel(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField('Процессор. Процессор', label = 'Процессор', max_length= 40, null= True)
```

view:

```
# хочу получить: Процессор
characterist_0001_pkModel.a1.label
```

Comment: Can you clarify, you want to access the label of the model field, not the form in the view? Are you using a form?

Comment: You want to have a description of your model once a new instance is created or in your form ?

Comment: I don't see a form, more code for what you're doing may help here, but at the moment it's somewhat unclear for lack of context.

Comment: I am sorry but you have to explain yourself in English ... @Леонид

Comment: @markwalker_ sorry. I want to get to the label of the model field, I gave the form only as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `_meta` object of the model instance and access fields *- which is an array*, and choose the field by index.

> These fields are ordered by the order they were defined in the model,
> 0 -> id, 1 -> a1, 2 -> ...etc

```
# supposing that characterist_0001_pkModel_object is an object of
# characterist_0001_pkModel Model.

characterist_0001_pkModel_object._meta.fields[1].verbose_name
```